# 2 listboxes selected items gui

Tags: windows, powershell, user-interface

I have q GUI with 2 listboxes like so:
[image]

I have a function moving items from left to right like so:

```
Function MoveRight (){
    $x = $listbox1.selecteditems
     @($x) | ForEach-Object {[void] $Listbox2.Items.Add($_);
         [void]$Listbox1.Items.Remove($_)} 
}

Function moveLeft(){
    $x = $listbox2.selecteditems
     @($x) | ForEach-Object {[void] $Listbox1.Items.Add($_);
         [void]$Listbox2.Items.Remove($_)} 
}
```

My goal is to take all the items that are currently on the right windows, and when the user press install- run a function to install them.

But this will not happen because the user can put in the rightbox whatever he likes, if he wont click on them, they wont be selected.

I was think of like a gloabal variable to hold the info when he's moving items from left to right but is there a better option to achive the goal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want all items in the right-hand listbox to be installed, why not simply iterate over the items and perform the install:

```
for ($i = 0; $i -lt $listbox2.Items.Count; $i++) {
    # perform the install on each item
}
```

If you want it to be visible for the user that all items in that box will be installed, you can select them all first:

```
$listbox2.BeginUpdate()
for ($i = 0; $i -lt $listbox2.Items.Count; $i++) {
    $listBox2.SetSelected($i, $true)
}
$listbox2.EndUpdate()
```

and then start installing all of them

This code of course goes into your `$installButton_Add_Click()` scriptblock.

Comment: Problem here is both left and right boxes are Listboxes. so when the user move items from left to right, everything may appear there, but he doesnt actually selecting anything on the rightbox, so actually when pressing install nothing will be selected unless he is selecting again items from the right listbox

Comment: @ShaharWeiss Yes, but that is exactly what my answer shows. Loop through all items in listbox2, either user selected or not and install it all. The second part of my answer shows how you can first select all items in listbox2, so the user can see what is happening when he/she clicks the Install button. Now, apparently, your code is installing **ONLY** the items that are selected. Use the second part to select all and then run your code to install the selected items.

Answer (score 1):

Agree with Theo on  selection.

As for installtion, use

```
$Listbox2.Items | % {
    $_ #this is the value of listbox item
    #pefrorm actions 
    }
```

for Install button click.